# How to restore User on Page reload in MongoDB Realm + VueJS App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongodb-realm

I use MongoDB Realm Client SDK in Javascript to login and get user info.
But on page reload user has to login again. I tried to store the user object in localstorage but I don't see any methods or functions to assign this info back to the Realm APP

How can I avoid this relogin for user in MongoDB Realm javascript app?